# How to calculate this type of limit? (solution verification)

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

The limit is: $$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{3^n+4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{5^n+8^{n+1}}}
$$

I've seen examples like this but with n-th root, not with square and cube root. I'm just asking for a hint, because I've not seen this type of example, so please don't downvote this.

Edit: Using the hint we get

$$\frac{\sqrt{4^n(\frac{3^n}{4^n} + 1)}}{\sqrt[3]{8^n (\frac{5^n}{8^n} + 8)}} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3^n}{4^n} +1}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{5^n}{8^n}+8}}$$ and this goes to $\frac{1}{2}$, because both fractions inside roots go to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Hint: Factor $4^n$ on the numerator and factor $8^n$ on the denominator

Comment: You should rely on the squeeze theorem and try to get simple bounds on the sequence.

Comment: $X=\dfrac{A^{1/2}}{B^{1/3}}\Rightarrow X^6=\dfrac{A^3}{B^2}$

Comment: My (**very informal**) personal intuition, which motivates the idea in the comment of @ThànhNguyễn is that : [1] in the numerator, the $~3^n~$ term is eventually dwarfed by the $~4^n~$ term, [2] in the denominator, the $~5^n~$ term is eventually dwarfed by the $~8^{n+1}~$ term, and $$[3] ~~~~\frac{\sqrt{4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{2^3 \times 8^n}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{\sqrt{3^n+4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{5^n+8^{n+1}}}=\sqrt[6]{\frac{(3^n+4^n)^3}{(5^n+8^{n+1})^2}}. $$

Recall
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} a_i u_i^n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}b_i v_i^n}=\frac{a_l}{b_k}$$, provided $u_l>u_i>0 $ for all $i\ne l$, $v_k>v_i>0$ for $i\ne k$ and $u_l=v_k$. (To prove this, you can multiply $\frac{1}{u_l}=\frac{1}{v_k}$ to ${\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} a_i u_i^n}$ and ${\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}b_i v_i^n}$ respectively.)

Now expand ${(3^n+4^n)^3}$ and ${(5^n+8^{n+1})^2}$, then apply the above fact. Note that $64^n$ and $64\cdot64^n$ is the dominating term in the expansion respectively. Hence the limit is
$$ \sqrt[6]{\frac{1}{64}}=\frac{1}{2} .$$
Remark: The last step used the fact that $\sqrt[6]{\cdot}$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

As $n\to\infty,$ [$3^n+4^n\sim4^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) (because $\frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n}=\left(\frac34\right)^n+1\to1$) and similarly, $5^n+8^{n+1}\sim8^{n+1}.$ Therefore,
$$\frac{\sqrt{3^n+4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{5^n+8^{n+1}}}\sim\frac{\sqrt{4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{8^{n+1}}}=\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac12,$$
i.e. $\frac{\sqrt{3^n+4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{5^n+8^{n+1}}}\to\frac12.$

Comment: fastest method (+1)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is elementary as it avoids applying the continuity of the square and the third roots.

We have $\sqrt{a+b}\le \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt[3]{a+b}\le \sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b} $ for $a,b>0.$ Hence$$\frac{\sqrt{3^n+4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{5^n+8^{n+1}}}\le {{3^{n/2}+2^n}\over {\sqrt[3]{8^{n+1}}}} \\ ={1\over 2}\left({3^{1/2}\over 2}\right)^n+{1\over 2}$$ On the  other hand $$\frac{\sqrt{3^n+4^n}}{\sqrt[3]{5^n+8^{n+1}} }\ge {2^n\over  5^{n/3}+2\cdot 2^n}={1\over \left({5^{1/3}\over 2}\right )^n+2}$$ By the squeeze rule the limit is equal ${1\over 2}.$